# Importing CSV data into HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I need to import data from csv file into form. I tried example from this topic:

[How to import CSV file into HTML form, and export HTML form to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042591/how-to-import-csv-file-into-html-form-and-export-html-form-to-csv-file/33042738)

Unfortunately it does not work for me. The file is opening, but no data are put into form.

My index.html file looks as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<input id="upload" type="file">

<form id="csvForm">
    <input id="a"></input>
    <input id="b"></input>
    <input id="c"></input>
    <input id="d"></input>
</form>
<button id="download">Download</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And script.js file:

```
document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", upload, false);
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download, false);

function upload(e) {

    var data = null;
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var csvData = event.target.result;

        var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(csvData);

        parsedCSV.forEach(function (d, i) {
            if (i == 0) return true; // skip the header
            document.getElementById(d[0]).value = d[1];
        });

    }
}

function download(e) {

    data = [["id","value"]];

    var f = d3.selectAll("#csvForm > input")[0];

    f.forEach(function(d,i){
        data.push([d.id, d.value]);
    });

    console.log(data);

    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    data.forEach(function (d, i) {
        dataString = d.join(",");
        csvContent += i < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "FormData.csv");
    link.click(); 
}
```

Shall I add something more? Any other library or framework?

Thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works well,
just move `<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>` tag at the end of your `<body>` tag

```
.
.
.
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I can't understand what exactly you need after updating your question, do you want to view the uploaded csv on the textboxes? if so..

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
</head>
<body>  
<input id="upload" type="file">

<form id="csvForm">
    <input id="a"></input>
    <input id="b"></input>
    <input id="c"></input>
    <input id="d"></input>
</form>
<button id="download">Download</button>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    

   document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", upload, false);
   document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download, false);
   var out = "";
   function upload(e) {
    document.getElementById('csvForm').innerHTML = "";

       var data = null;
       var file = e.target.files[0];

       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsText(file);
       reader.onload = function (event) {
           var csvData = event.target.result;

           var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(csvData);

           parsedCSV.forEach(function (d, i) {
               if (i == 0) return true; // skip the header
               if(d.constructor === Array){
                    // console.log(d);
                    // document.getElementById(d[0]).value = d[1];
                    createForm(d);
                  }
           });

       }
   }

   function createForm(csv){
    // console.log(out);

    for (var i in csv) {
       out+='<input value="' +csv[i]+ '">';
    }
    document.getElementById('csvForm').innerHTML = out;
    out+='<br>';
   }

   function download(e) {

       data = [["id","value"]];

       var f = d3.selectAll("#csvForm > input")[0];

       f.forEach(function(d,i){
           data.push([d.id, d.value]);
       });

       console.log(data);

       var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
       data.forEach(function (d, i) {
           dataString = d.join(",");
           csvContent += i < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
       });

       var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
       var link = document.createElement("a");
       link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
       link.setAttribute("download", "FormData.csv");
       link.click(); 
   }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now it works as it should. Thank you very much for solving my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Once again thank you for help. But I've got another problem. Now I need to add this uploading control to my web application. The content is generated automatically depending on users behaviour. The part of the code responsible for opening the form is as follows:

```
function  createFormOrderDetailsCSV()
{
    var out='';
    out+='<input id="upload" type="file">';
    out+='<form id="csvForm">';
    out+='<input id="a"></input>';
    out+='<input id="b"></input>';
    out+='<input id="c"></input>';
    out+='<input id="d"></input>';
    out+='</form>';
    out+='<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>';
    document.getElementById("OrderDetailsContainer").innerHTML=out;
    document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", upload, false);
}


function upload(e) {

    var data = null;
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var csvData = event.target.result;

        var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(csvData);

        parsedCSV.forEach(function (d, i) {
            if (i == 0) return true; // skip the header
            document.getElementById(d[0]).value = d[1];
        });

    }
}
```

And again it is the same. File is open, but no data is transferred to the text input controls in the form.

Comment: i can't understand what exactly u need, you want to view the uploaded csv on the textboxes?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I need. I need to put csv data into a form inputs, and send them to a database from the form. I am ok with sending to DB, I just can't go over retrieving data from csv file.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer check it and tell me if this what you need

Comment: fyk my code needs alot of modifications, im just trying to figure out your major needs :)

Comment: I've got function createFormOrderDetailsCSV() which generates HTML code and assings it to a container that is a part of other form loaded earlier. So I need to work on content of this function, as it is a part of some bigger web application that is succesfully working. I need just to add possibility to load data from CSV files. The first code in this post was just for training, so to make sure, that code is working on its own and now I need to include it in my web application.

Comment: yes im just trying to figure out what you need, man createFormOrderDetailsCSV doesn't make anything you just hard coded it to print 4 textboxes and not depends on any csv file

Comment: i mean if your csv file has 20 rows for example so createFormOrderDetailsCSV() will print 4 textboxes regardless, got my pont!

Comment: This function creates form with 4 texboxes and file upload button. The line document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", upload, false) should check for changes and run function upload(e) as it was in first code. But it doesn't. I can click upload button and OS API file upload window opens, but after choosing the file no data goes to text iputs.

Comment: ofcourse u wont see any data in your textboxes, you are calling the an undefined id here 'document.getElementById(d[0]).value = d[1];' just console d[0] and trace what you wrote carefully

Comment: But in the first example d[0] also was undefined, but data were loaded into textboxes.

Comment: that's because you hard coded the input and the output, i mean that you added 4 inputs with id matches your first column in your csv ;) thats why it worked well with you, got what i mean

Comment: But in both examples it is the same code. Same function upload(e) and same html. The only difference is that html is loaded after the function createFormOrderDetailsCSV() is called. In both cases I use the same csv file, elements have got the same ids, etc.

Comment: you didn't call createFormOrderDetailsCSV() in your example, you just created it

Comment: I call this function in other place. I post just a small part of the code. This function is for sure called, because all the controls (4 inputs and button) are loaded and visible for user.

Comment: The problem is that d3.js is not included. I put some alerts to check where the code stops to work, and it stops on the line var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(csvData); in function upload(e). I need to include d3.js in other way than it is done now. I tried to include it also in html that calls createFormOrderDetailsCSV() function, but it didn't help.

Comment: I've already soled the problem. I included d3 in php script that is responsible for loading the first elements on page. I included it also before, but in version 5 (d3.v5.js) which wasn't work.